# how to get the latest console output in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm testing a site that mixes AngularJS and non angularJS pages.
One of the things i try to do is see if an exception is triggred due to an operation the user has committed.
The way i'm doing it is through the web console.

To get the console output i'm doing as follows:

```
 afterEach(function(){
 browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLogs) {
     browserLogs.forEach(function(log){
         if (log.level.value > 900) { 
              // it's an error log
              console.log('Browser console error!');
              console.log(log.message);
         }
      });
  });     
});
```

the operation that supposed to trigger the exception is done in the last 'it' statment of the describe block.
after the operation is over the exception is not caught (other messages from the console do), and i've noticed that if i add an 'it' block (even an empty one that does nothing) after the mentioned 'it' block the exception is caught.

```
at the mentioned 'it' block i do the following: 
1. press a link that directs me to the wanted page
2. issue browser.waitForAngular() command
3. perform the operation

attached my conf file configurations:

framework: 'jasmine2',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
rootElement: '.keypressEvents.ng-scope',
allScriptsTimeout: 300000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  onComplete: null,
  isVerbose: false,
  showColors: true,
  includeStackTrace: true
},
onPrepare: function(){
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
        dest: '/protractor test/project/test/screenshots',
        filename: 'my-report.html',
        reportOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
        captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true,
        showQuickLinks: true
    })
 );
```

so my question is why isn't the exception caught when the operation is done on the last 'it' block and what should i do to catch it.